# SQL query to make one column for every date in range

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

Give a simple table like this:

```
ClientCode | Date       | Amount
--------------------------------
1          | 2014-01-01 | 10
1          | 2014-01-01 | 20
2          | 2014-01-01 | 30
1          | 2014-01-02 | 15
```

I need a query that would list the count of rows for every client for every day like this:

```
ClientCode | day2014-01-01 | day2014-01-02 | day2014-01-03
1          |             2 |             1 |             0
2          |             1 |             0 |             0
```

I could make a CASE for every day but I need it for 120 days and about 80000 clients.

Any advice?

Comment: Search for `crosstab` in the [`tablefunc` module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html).

Comment: Likely a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3002499/519015)